# Make custom Wait Popup wait Until activity is done MS Access 2010 - 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a custom Popup that I call whenever an activity takes more than a second.  Example:

```
 PopupMsg("Getting records")
```

It makes a nice box that just shows the user something is happening, then it quietly disappears when the activity is done.

It works great for anything that only takes about 3 seconds, but beyond that, it disappears and then the user is left with the impression that the activity is finished. I'd like to make it stay up exactly as long as whatever activity is happening, but I've never been successful in determining this. I'd like to make sure all screen calculations are done before the popup disappears.

Here's how I implement my PopupMsg routine

```
Public Function PopUpMsg(strMsg As String, Optional strTitle As String)
Dim frmWait As New Form_Wait

If strTitle <> "" Then
    frmWait.OpenForm strMsg & "...", strTitle
Else
    frmWait.OpenForm strMsg & "..."
End If

End Function
```

Wait (A form called 'Wait' contains the following code)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Property Let Message(ByVal MessageText As String)
    Me.MessageLabel.Caption = MessageText
    Me.Repaint
End Property
Public Property Get Message() As String
    Message = Me.MessageLabel.Caption
End Property

Public Property Let Title(ByVal TitleText As String)
    Me.Caption = TitleText
End Property
Public Property Get Title() As String
    Title = Me.Caption
End Property

Public Function OpenForm(Optional MessageText As Variant, _
        Optional TitleText As Variant) As Boolean
    If Not IsMissing(MessageText) Then Me.MessageLabel.Caption = MessageText
    If Not IsMissing(TitleText) Then Me.Caption = TitleText
    Me.Visible = True
    Me.Repaint
    OpenForm = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're opening a form through a class instantiation, it doesn't actually persist, and gets removed as soon as Access decides to do garbage collection and sees there's no reference to the form. If you want a form that persists until code execution is done, the best way is to pass back that form:

```
Public Function PopUpMsg(strMsg As String, Optional strTitle As String) As Object
    Set PopUpMsg = New Form_Wait
    If strTitle <> "" Then
        PopUpMsg.OpenForm strMsg & "...", strTitle
    Else
        PopUpMsg.OpenForm strMsg & "..."
    End If
End Sub
```

The rest of your code is still valid

You can call it like this:

```
Dim WaitForm As Object
Set WaitForm = PopupMsg("Getting records")
```

That way, you're still depending on garbage collection to remove the form, but it will close as soon as the function calling it is done.

You could also just open the form through `DoCmd.OpenForm "Wait"`, reference it through the `Forms` collection, and close it using `DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"` at the end of your function, but then you'll have to close it actively. Full code for that approach:

```
Public Function PopUpMsg(strMsg As String, Optional strTitle As String)
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Wait"
    Dim frmWait As Form
    Set frmWait = Forms!Wait
    If strTitle <> "" Then
        frmWait.OpenForm strMsg & "...", strTitle
    Else
        frmWait.OpenForm strMsg & "..."
    End If
End Sub
```

Call it: `PopupMsg("Getting records")`

Close it at the end of execution: `DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"`

If you're not calling `DoEvents` in your code, there's another alternative:
Open the form using `DoCmd.OpenForm "Wait"`, set it's `TimerInterval` to `1`, and add `DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name` to it's `Form_Close` event

Comment: Can you give me a 'Calling' example of the new implementation.  I did this: 1. Public Function PopUpMsg(strMsg As String, Optional strTitle As String) As Object
    Set PopUpMsg = New Form_Wait and called it like this  
Dim WaitForm as Object
Set WaitForm = PopupMsg("Calculating")
DoCmd.Open WaitForm   
(Causes an error - what do I fix)

Comment: That sounds like you're using all different approaches half, and at the same time. I will rewrite it with more code. You can ignore everything after "You can also ..." since that's about a totally different approach (so no `DoCmd`, just those first two lines, and using that existing form code)

Comment: Thank you. Still eager to see what you write, simply because I've gotten used to calling my PopUpMsg, knowing that it will only handle small tasks. Nevertheless, I was able to get it to work by calling the form and closing it after. It would be nice for the PopUpMsg to work the way calling the DoCmd.OpenForm "Wait" and closing it at the end did.

Comment: I've already rewritten the first approach. Just see the answer above

Comment: Thank you for both alternatives. I see it.

Comment: Well, does it work? (if not, please give some feedback, else, mark as answered)

Comment: Yes.  Above, my nevertheless comment states that.  I just figured I would test the PopupMsg more this morning before marking it.  Thanks again.